# Authentication in service worker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm dabbling into the art of service workers and PWA. I have trouble finding out more about authentication for the service worker. I want to poll or have a websocket to a backend, where i would need to authenticate. The service worker would be registered within the same domain and enabled when the user is already authenticated. But what happens when the user closes that session, will the service worker still work with the login cookie?

Answer (score 2):

If the user closes the session/logs off then any Fetch request the SW performs that requires authentication will fail.

FYI, I asked about Session Expiry without a client present, as opposed to the user actively terminating the session [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1231)

Sadly the only work being done on SW at the moment is caching everything, offline-first, over-tuning, and "Look! I've built a proxy-server and CloudFlare on the client" :-(